# How i can truncate table on MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use bellow code to TRUNCATE TABLE 'table_name', but it does not work. this is my PHP code

```
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
    mysql_select_db($myDB, $connection);
    mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE table_name", $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

is that wrong?

Comment: _How_ does it not work? More details required. As an aside, mysql_* functions have long been deprecated from PHP5, and removed entirely form PHP7. They should not be used.

Comment: _Is it wrong_ Well you tell us! Does it work, if (YES) then its aint wrong. if (NO) then it is wrong

Comment: Please don't continue learning old `mysql` api

Comment: i'm try using PHPMyAdmin, if i try `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` using SQL query the table has been empty, but if i try in my PHP page, it does not work.

Comment: Yes, but what does `does not work` mean to you!? What _does_ happen? Is that line of code actually running? Are there warnings / message output? Is there anything in the error log? General debugging.

Comment: So do i have to change the script?

Comment: @Jon Stirling I mean, the table `table_name` not empty

Comment: No Warning maessage

Comment: Good news, i emptying the table